# Genymotion and video ads

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, ads, genymotion

I run Android 4.4.4 in Genymotion. I [installed the Google Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20013322/395857), which include Google Play. Through Google Play I installed the game [Sky Force 2014](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.idreams.skyforcehd&hl=en).

Why can't I click on the button in the red rectangle area in the screenshot below?

[image]

This button is used to display some 30-second video ad, which gives me one additional spaceship.

Maybe the fact that the button is greyed out mean that for some reason video ads don't work in my  Genymotion virtual device? Any other ideas or solutions to try to fix it?

Everything works fine on my phone (Samsung Galaxy S5 (SM-G900A)).

Comment: Do you have any AD blocker installed at all?

Comment: None. I do see ads in some other apps.

Comment: Just covering the bases.  Did you deny any permissions?  Have you restricted any services, activities,  broadcast receivers, or other controls that would keep the ad from being displayed?

Comment: @HasH_BrowN No: I kept Genymotion's default settings.

Comment: The ad might be Admob. If that is the case,  then you need the Admob unit ID. To have a Admob account, you need AdWords account setup.

Comment: I think Genymotion can't play video ads (Google IMA), for some reason I can't figure out. Ads play fine on Nexus 10.

Comment: Have you tried this on Bluestacks if you have? will try myself an update later.. i think that might be due to the ads unavailability..in some game to earn gold i click watch video to earn one gold..but it wont load and will show a mesage that video is currently not available pls try later message...

Comment: @ Lucky I haven't tried bluestack, too bulky :/